# Adding AD User - P.O Box and Zip Code information Via Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a list of users, Which serve as Shared Mailboxes - user objects,
In active directory.

The list is stored under TXT file ( usernames ).
in format:

> user.name1
> user.name2
>  
>   etc..

I Would like to add the following values for each user, listed in the file:
-PostalCode "01010101"
-POBox "000"

Previously , i have seen something like that suggested, with using
Set-ADUser command, something like:

```
Set-ADUser -Filter "UserPrincipalName -eq '$($_.userprincipalname)'" -PostalCode "01010101" -POBox "000"
```

This example is taken from another question , but, it has different parameters.

Please assist to create a complete script , which does the complete action.

Thanks everyone for your assistance.

Comment: how are the users seperated in the text file? Whitespace, new line, some other characters?

Comment: hi, thanks for your reply,new line

Comment: Where do you get the postal code from? The TXT example doesn't show a postal code. Where do you want to add the postal code to? To the TXT file or the Active Directory account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the TXT file contains usernames (SamAccountName), you can pipe the username values into a foreach loop and send them to `Set-ADUser`.

```
Get-Content Usernames.txt | Foreach-Object {
    Set-ADUser -Identity $_ -PostalCode "01010101" -POBox "000"
}
```

The `-Filter` parameter can accept most AD attribute ldap display names for the given object class. The operator set is limited, but `-eq` is included. Using the pipeline into `Foreach-Object`, `$_` will represent the current object in the pipeline, which will be one username from the TXT file. SamAccountName is used in the filter based on the assumption that usernames are SamAccountName values. If they are not, you can tweak the filter accordingly.